# Requests.package.urllib3 error

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib3

I am a Python rookie and have been exploring the language.  Things are going well since I do have a fairly basic programming background and I can understand the general structure.  However, recently, I think that I did something to break urllib3 because my app was working before and now it fails and I can no longer import urllib3 through the interactive interpreter.

Here is the code:

```
import json, requests, ssl

devID = "xxxx" <--xxx is included for privacy/security purposes
varName = "Current_T"
AToken = "xxx" <--xxx is included for privacy/security purposes
spark_url = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/%s/%s?access_token=%s" % (devID,varName,AToken)
r = requests.get(spark_url)
data = r.json()
jsonData = "result"
CurrentTemp = data[jsonData]
print("Current temp is: %i") % CurrentTemp
```

This pretty basic stuff and it worked perfectly until earlier this morning.  The error I now receive is the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/python-learning $ python ./spark-read-variable.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./spark-read-variable.py", line 1, in <module>
    import json, requests, ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 95, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'
```

So far, I have tried the following to address the situation and nothing has fixed it.:

1. Upgrade requests and urllib3
2. Remove and reinstall urllib3
3. Reboot Raspberry Pi <- Probably a dumb idea, but I tried anyway

The only thing that I can think of that could be causing this was that I tried to use pip to install stmtplib and email.utils and both failed.

One final data point is that if I try to import urllib3 through the interactive interpreter, I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/fields.py", line 1, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you happen to have named one of your own modules `email.py`? The traceback seems to indicate that, and that would shadow the standard library module `email`, leading to the errors you see.

Comment: LOL!  That was exactly it!  I did create an email.py and did not realize this.  Sorry for the complete newbie problem and thank you for the quick response!

Comment: you're welcome - happened to most of use at some point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you named one of your own modules `email.py`.

This will shadow the standard library module `email`, from which `urllib3` tries to import `email.utils`, and then fails.

Rename your module to something else, and you should be good.

---

**Note**: The indicator for this is the following line:

```
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
```

Unlike the other modules in the traceback, this line does not include an absolute path, but is instead a relative path / just a filename. This indicates that Python picked up the `email.py` module from the current working directory instead of its `site-packages`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and even more importantly, the clarification into how I can diagnose the situation myself if/when it happens in the future.